trouble with instal on epyc 4004 system
I am installing Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS on a epyc 4004 system. It would not install using the normal “try and install” option, but had to use the “HWE kernel” option to install.
I am trying to understand if this would present any stability option long term and why a normal "try and install ubuntu" option would just hang.
system specs:
ASRACK B650D4U with latest bios 20.03
AMD EPYC 4344P
32GB of unreg ECC ram 1 stick
WD black m.2 HDD
